# ajax combobox dropdown button not display

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a question I can't click the dropdown button in ajax:comboBox in a modal popup

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server">
     <div class="modal fade" id="setup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="head4">Title HEAD modal</h4>
            </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-7 col-xs-7 col-7 col-md-7">
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                    <Triggers>
                                    </Triggers>
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="modelistInject" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" >
                                        </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
                                        <asp:Button runat="server" />
                                      
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </div>
```

when I click button from <asp:Button runat="server"/> It will show dropdown button

[image: image when click button]

when I do not click it, it does not display a dropdown button.

[image: image when not clicked]

Comment: Why did you put the panel outside the updatepanel?

Comment: I dont know why to, Will it be a problem?